# View entire check in history TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

Have been searching all over the internet but struggling to find my answer to this simple question.

I'm using TFS with VS 2010 and all I want to do is view the check in history **NOT** just for a single file.

That's helpful when I need to use it, but I  want a bigger history so I can just see EACH check in and what comments I put next to it.

If I select the solution or the main project, for whatever reason, I only get a subset of the checkins done (I assume because changes did not directly affect those higher levels, but not sure)

Answer (score 121, accepted):

You can right click on any folder in the **Source Control Explorer** (not the solution opened in Visual Studio) and do view history. That should show all changes sets that has happened in that folder tree. Is this what you want ?

Comment: yes exactly, thank you. Makes sense now, when right clicking the solution in VS is implying the individual file...

Comment: This does not let you see every single checkin made in an entire solution or project (it only shows change sets that affected the solution file or proj file, which most checkins do not) It only works for folders. Is there no way to view every single changeset made in a solution??

Comment: @Drkawashima In _Source Control Explorer_, You have to _navigate to the root folder_, of the solution and choose 'View History' by right click. I'm getting every single checkin we did.

Comment: @Manivannan Nagarajan, I did the same thing it doesn't show everything! it only show project/solution changes. It does not show individual file changes.

Comment: @drkawashima, In most organisations I've known, the solution file is in one folder and projects are in subfolders. I want to see all changes to all files in those subfolders, which I think is what you might be saying.

Answer (score 24):

To do this from the **Solution Explorer**:

1. **Right click the solution** -> **Source Control** -> **View History**
2. In the Source Location path textbox, **delete '*.sln'** from the path and **press enter**

Just a simple way which doesn't require accessing the Source Control Explorer since I rarely have it open.

Comment: @drkawashima This technique shows changesets that affect files within subfolders

Answer (score 6):

Go to Home folder of the **Source Control Explorer**, right click on it and select "**View History**".

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution for VS2017

- `Team` Menu Item -> `Manage Connections`
- Double Click your project
- Hit `Changes`
- `Actions` Link -> `View History`